# Hueman WordPress Theme ... Cannot Enable Comments On Posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog that is using the free Hueman WordPress Theme.  For some reason, no matter what settings I seem to enable/disable, the ability for users to add comments will not show up on my blog posts.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?  Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this theme provides the enable/disable comments option? Have you checked in documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Comments stop working for me in Hueman when I use custom posts.
For some reason the comments are closed.
Workaround for this is to force open the comments.
Just add this in your functions.php file in your child theme:

```
function my_override_comments_open( $open ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $open = true;
    }
    return $open;
}
add_filter('comments_open', 'my_override_comments_open', 1000);
```

I don't like comments on pages, just posts. So I use is_single() check.
If you want comments on all posts & pages just remove it.
Hope this helps.